# How are planetary gearboxes held together?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, gears

I see that the housings of most planetary gearboxes consist of 3 parts: a front cap, a ring gear and a rear cap. Here's a common design:

[image]
[image]

In designs similar to this, the rear cap and the ring gear are held together by several (torx) screws. But how about the front cap and the ring gear? There's no sign of any screw or fastener. There is a circlip on the shaft, but I believe that's for holding the bearings in and not for holding the front cap. Does anyone know how the front cap is held fixed? Here's a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMr9ciatm2s

Comment: There are two holes shown where screws go through into the casing, seen clearly left side on the outer ring of the cap.

Comment: @SolarMike I believe those are tapped holes for fastening fixating the gearbox to something like a bracket. Also, the ring gear won't have enough material for tapped holes in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be 4 thru holes on the front cap (1 is missing due to the section view). There are probably tapped holes in the ring gear, screws keep the cap in place.

This could also sit in a housing with stops next to the front and bottom housings.

Comment: Those 4 holes are tapped for mounting the gearbox to something like a bracket.

Comment: Then there is probably a similar fixture point for the rear cap, with that and the front cap bracket fixed to a chassis.

Comment: That's what I thought, but there doesn't seem to be any screw near the front cap: https://img.directindustry.com/images_di/photo-mg/7056-13952899.jpg

Comment: Could just be press fit then. All spur gear train, doesn't generate any axial force.

Comment: You mean the front cap is press fit to the ring gear? I wonder why they all follow this design rather than use screws like they do to the back cap.

Comment: Yes. Probably cost, fewer machining operations and less hardware. "If it don't make dollars it don't make sense."

Probably higher torque at the back cap, more chance of it slipping and galling.

Comment: Shouldn't torque always be lower at the back/input cap though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109783/discussion-between-jko-and-john-m).

Answer (score 1):

A possible method is that the circlips hold the front cap to the assembly which is slid into the housing and the rear cap holds it togther with the 4 cap screws, given there is little axial force generated by the gearing system.

The frint cap can also be a press fit into the casing especially as the section does not show any o-rings...

Comment: But it's often the case that the gearbox's front cap bracket holds the motor's weight as well, which can easily be a few kg. That'd be a lot of weight for a circlip, wouldn't it?

Comment: You'd be surprised the load a retaining ring can handle

Comment: But the circlip wouldn't stop the the shaft along with the front cap from sliding out, right?

Comment: @JohnM. Have you dismantled any of these? Or are you just working from pictures?

Comment: @SolarMike I've been doing that, but the front cap and ring gear are together. I didn't want to cause too much damage.